# How to change workspace JRE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

While creating new Java project in Eclipse I got following warning "The current workspace uses 1.4 JRE..."
[image]

I have JRE7 on my system. I have added following lines in `eclipse.ini`

```
-vm 
C:\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

I have added JRE7 to `Installed JREs` through Windows -> Preferences-> Installed JREs.
[image]
Still under `Compiler` tab I can see only `compiler compliance level` till 6.
[image]
How can I change workspace JRE to JRE 7 ?

Comment: Can you post how your "Installed JRE" looks like?

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: I have added a screen shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 7 support is only available since [Eclipse Indigo SR1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (released about a month ago). So, upgrade Eclipse.

Comment: From where it picks JRE 1.4 ? Where I can see which JRE is used by workspace ?

Comment: You're using an old Eclipse version which does **not** support Java 7. The behaviour is unspecified. As said, you need to upgrade Eclipse to at least Indigo SR1 (version 3.7.1).

Answer (score 0):

I also have jre7, and it really doesn't matter if it only says that is compliant with 1.6, because the project will look for the java compiler specified by the jre/jdk used in the project.

I also recommend you use the jdk instead of the jre, and set the environment variable JAVA_HOME, there's lots of tutorials on this in Google.

Comment: @alveinbaena: Thanks for suggestions. Any special reason / advantage for JDK instead of JRE ?

Comment: The "JDK" is the Java Development Kit. I.e., the JDK is the bundle of software that you can use to develop Java based software. The "JRE" is the Java Runtime Environment. I.e., the JRE is an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine which actually executes Java programs.

Typically, each JDK contains one (or more) JRE's along with the various development tools like the Java source compilers, bundling and deployment tools, debuggers, development libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue where it is compiling with 1.4 but the workspace Preferences Compiler setting is 1.6 seems to be the issue described in this bug:

Bug 499675 - Global compiler settings ignored after restarting, defaults to 1.4 even though 1.8 displayed
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499675

where the workaround is to change the workspace setting to a different version number and then back to 1.6. That would enable the workspace to compile with 1.6. 
To compile with 1.7 you'd need to upgrade eclipse as in BalusC's answer.