# Eclipse Neon does not install on my Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, jvm, eclipse-neon

when i tried to install Eclipse Neon on my Mac Sierra, it prompted:
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for the this product.

However when I check the java version on terminal: it says:
java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)

Anyone knows what is the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse not recognizing JVM 1.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246910/eclipse-not-recognizing-jvm-1-8)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Eclipse popup window says:
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for the this product.
Version: 1.8 or greater is required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had orginally installed the JRE, and did a search for "java" across the hard disk, and it found a JavaApplet plugin.  I deleted this, and then installed the latest jdk (144) dmg.  Running the eclipse installer then worked.  (so, it was just a java environment problem for me).