# What are the steps to configure Struts 1.3 in Eclipse, with the open declaration and open implementation option on the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, struts, struts-1

I've an existing project(in SVN Respository) developed using Struts1. Now I need to import it in the eclipse IDE.

When I try to import the project, I've 2 problems :

1. If, I place the files from my project to a newly created "Dynamic Web Project", its showing errors with all the javascript, jsp and java files(All import statements are shown as error)
2. If, I use SVN Checkout/Import, its working fine, no errors. But the links are not available on the java code, like when I click on a function/variable name, it should go the function/variable declaration/definition(Eclipse - Open Declaration/Open Implementation).

Someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would always prefer to import projects as Maven projects (if they are) so that it would downloads the dependencies on the go.

If the import statements are not recognized means, you should configure the corresponding JRE. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861424/how-to-change-workspace-jre-in-eclipse) may help you.

Finally, there are so many aspects while configuring an existing project. Please Check your project Wiki if any. If not do create one while you short out them.